# Broken Textures - Adobe substance painter

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting, texture-baking, uv-image-editor

When I apply any material or smart material, some UV islands looks like on image and I don't know why or how to repair it.

Model made in Blender, mesh maps are generated in Adobe Substance Painter.

Maybe change some settings when I baked mesh maps?

[image]